# How to properly define and use a schema in Apache Beam Python?

Tags: python, apache-beam

The following code attempts to read data from a source, define a schema and perform a SQLTransform.

```
...

class RowSchema(typing.NamedTuple):
    colA: str
    colB: typing.Optional[str]
    
beam.coders.registry.register_coder(RowSchema, beam.coders.RowCoder)

def run(argv=None):
  ...
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    query = '''
    SELECT
      colA, colB
    FROM `{}`
    ''' \
      .format(
        known_args.table
      )

    pcol = (p 
    | 'read from BQ' >>
     beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
      gcs_location=known_args.execution_gcs_location,
      query=query,
      use_standard_sql=True,
      )
    | 'ToRow' >> beam.Map(
      lambda x: RowSchema(**x)).with_output_types(RowSchema)
    | SqlTransform(
        """
        ...
        """)
    | beam.Map(print)
    )

...
```

However, it results in the following error:

```
  File "/home/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 423, in encode
    return value.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' [while running 'ToRow']
```

Using the same structure, the following pipeline works correctly:

```
pcol = (p
    | "Create" >> beam.Create(
        [{'colA': 'a1', 'colB': 'b1'}, {'colA': 'a2', 'colB': None}])
    | 'ToRow' >> beam.Map(lambda x: RowSchema(**x)).with_output_types(RowSchema)
    | SqlTransform(
        """
        ...
        """)
    | beam.Map(print)
    )
```

What seems to be missing in example 1 is converting the input data into an instance of [beam.pvalue.Row](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.pvalue.html#apache_beam.pvalue.Row), which is the case in example 2 but not in example 1.

How can I convert the input into Row objects for use with a static schema, assuming that was actually the problem?

The structure used is based on the following references: [1](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#inferring-schemas) [2](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.sql.html)

The [bigquery module](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html) also has built-in schemas, but only for BigQuery writes.

I've also checked the examples including [this one](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/sql_taxi.py) which uses dynamic schemas that wouldn't work for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out colA was actually an INTEGER in BigQuery, so simply changing its type to int in the schema definition solves the problem.